# Adding a Web.config to classic asp errors

Tags: asp-classic, web-config

I am adding a web.config file to my classic ASP project.

Here is the Web.config file,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
     <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
          <asp enableChunkedEncoding="false" /> 
        </system.webServer>
     </configuration>
```

When I run on my localhost, I get this error,

```
 HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed
```

I have added in a location path pointing to "Default Web Site" that seems to load the page, but not what I want to do, since this is not just for my local machine.

I'm not sure where to go from here to get the page to load.

Comment: The <asp> element was introduced in IIS 7.0. What version of IIS is your localhost?

Comment: The version I am using is IIS 7.0.